# For what value(s) of the parameter a is it possible to find explicit formulas ( without integrals)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For what value(s) of the parameter a is it possible to find explicit formulas ( without integrals)  for the solution to
$$\dfrac {dy}{dt} = aty + e^{-t^2}$$

I tried solving the question by the method of finding the integrating factor of the differential equation of the form $dy/dt + P(t)y = Q(t)$ but could not reach any conclusion as I was unable to solve the integral. Plus the question says no integrals are to be used. now I am clueless. Kindly help me.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Ihave corrected the mistake

Comment: Hint: $\frac{dy}{dt} - aty = e^{\frac{at^2}{2}}\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-\frac{at^2}{2}}y\right)$

Comment: Cf. Liouville's theorem $\int e^{-t^2}dt$ can't be expressed in elementary forms.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac {dy}{dt} -aty = e^{-t^2}$$
The integrating facvtor should be $$\mu(t)=e^{-at^2/2}$$
$$(ye^{-at^2/2})'=e^{-t^2}e^{-at^2/2}$$
$$(ye^{-at^2/2})'=e^{-t^2(1+a/2)}$$
You can't find a closed form for the integral of the  RHS except for:
$$\dfrac a2+1=0$$
Then you can find a closed form for $y(t)$.
$$(y(t)e^{-at^2/2})'=1$$

Comment: Please explain a bit what is meant by not being able to find the closed form for the integral?

Comment: @Understandingthings the  gaussian-like integral $I$ has no  closed form with elementary functions.. $I=\int e^{-ct^2}dt$ Except when $c=0$ then the integral $I=\int dt=t+A$ where $A$ is a constant..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

As @achille hui commented
$$y'=at y \implies y=C\,e^{\frac{a t^2}{2}}$$ Variation of parameters gives
$$e^{\frac{a t^2}{2}} C'=e^{-t^2}\implies C'=e^{-\frac{a+2}{2}  t^2}\implies C=K+\int e^{-\frac{a+2}{2}  t^2}\,dt$$ and this remembers me a quite simple integral.

Comment: Could you please help me sollving this particular integral. A hint is more than enough. Thanku.

Comment: @Understandingthings. Think about $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$